# Creating a database using a "Two Layer LinkedLists"

Tags: java, list, linked-list, abstract-data-type

Trying to setup a program using ADTs for a college course that sorts out `Storm` Objects using a multi-layer LinkedList. Here is what I need to do.

1. *Use a two-level linked list to organize the information within the database.*
2. *The nodes in the upper-level linked list will represent years, with one node per year.*
3. *Each year node will contain a reference to a linked list of storms for that year.*
4. *You should maintain the items in each linked list in sorted order, sorting the upper list by year (in numerical order, low-to-high) and the lower list by name (in standard dictionary order).*
5. *You may use any variation on linked lists which you desire; dummy head nodes, head/end pointers, doubly-linked lists, etc..*
6. *You may implement additional classes as desired in order to manage the list.*

Can anyone walk me through this? Im stumped and have tried too hard thinking about this.

I already have 4 different classes for the two lists

- YearNode.java
- YearList.java
- StormNode.java
- StormList.java
- Storm.java

Here is the code:

**YearNode.java**

```
    public class YearNode
{

        int year;
        YearNode next;
        StormNode sNext;

    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    public StormNode getSNext()
    {
        return sNext;
    }

    public YearNode getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void setNext(YearNode next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setSNext(StormNode next)
    {
        this.sNext = sNext;
    }
}
```

**YearList.java**

```
    public class YearList
{
    YearNode head;
    YearNode sHead;

    public YearList()
    {
        YearNode head = null;
        YearNode sHead = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return(head == null);
    }

    public boolean isStormEmpty()
    {
        return(sHead == null);
    }

    public void setSList(StormNode node)
    {
        StormNode sHead = node;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        YearNode current = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(current != null)
        {
            counter++;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public int get(int index)
    {
        int size = size();
        YearNode current = head;

        if((index > size) || (index < 0))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        else
        {
            int counter = index;
            while(counter != 0)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
                counter--;
            }
            return current.getYear();
        }
    }

    public void add(int index, int year)
    {
        if((index < 0) || (index > size()))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        YearNode current = head;
        YearNode previous = null;
        while (index > 0)
        {
            index--;
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        YearNode Splice = new YearNode();
        Splice.setYear(year);
        Splice.setNext(current);
        if(previous == null)
        {
            head = Splice;
        }
        else
        {
            previous.setNext(Splice);
        }
    }

    public int remove(int index)
    {
        if((index < 0) || (index > size()))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        YearNode current = head;
        YearNode previous = null;
        while (index > 0)
        {
            index--;
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        if(previous == null)
        {
            head = current.getNext();
        }
        else
        {
            previous.setNext(current.getNext());
        }

        return current.getYear();

    }

    public void removeAll()
    {
            head = null;
    }
}
```

**StormNode.java**

```
 public class StormNode
{

        Storm storm;
        StormNode next;

    public Storm getStorm()
    {
        return storm;
    }

    public StormNode getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setStorm(Storm storm)
    {
        this.storm = storm;
    }

    public void setNext(StormNode next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

**StormList.java**

```
    public class StormList
{
    StormNode head;

    public StormList()
    {
        StormNode head = null;
    }

    public StormNode getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return(head == null);
    }

    public int size()
    {
        StormNode current = head;
        int counter = 0;
        while(current != null)
        {
            counter++;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public Object get(int index)
    {
        int size = size();
        StormNode current = head;
        if((index >= size) || (index < 0))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        else
        {
            int counter = index;
            while(counter != 0)
            {
                current = current.getNext();
                counter--;
            }
            return current.getStorm();
        }
    }

    public void add(int index, Storm Storm)
    {
        if((index < 0) || (index > size()))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        StormNode current = head;
        StormNode previous = null;
        while (index > 0)
        {
            index--;
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        StormNode Splice = new StormNode();
        Splice.setStorm(Storm);
        Splice.setNext(current);
        if(previous == null)
        {
            head = Splice;
        }
        else
        {
            previous.setNext(Splice);
        }
    }

    public Object remove(int index)
    {
        if((index < 0) || (index > size()))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        StormNode current = head;
        StormNode previous = null;
        while (index > 0)
        {
            index--;
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        if(previous == null)
        {
            head = current.getNext();
        }
        else
        {
            previous.setNext(current.getNext());
        }

        return current.getStorm();

    }

    public void removeAll()
    {
            head = null;
    }
}
```

**Storm.java**

```
    public class Storm{

      private int year; //
      private String name;
      private int startDay;
      private int endDay;
      private int category; 


      public Storm(int year, String name, int startDay, int endDay, int category){
         this.year = year;
         this.name = name;
         this.startDay = startDay;
         this.endDay = endDay;
         this.category = category;

      }

      public Storm()
      {
         this.year = 0;
         this.name = "";
         this.startDay = 0;
         this.endDay = 0;
         this.category = 7;
      }


      public String getName()
      {
         return this.name;
      }

      public int getYear()
      {
         return this.year;
      }

        public int getStartDay()
      {
         return this.startDay;
      }

        public int getEndDay()
      {
         return this.endDay;
      }

        public int getCategory()
      {
         return this.category;
      }

      public String getFormattedStartDay()
      {
            String startDayReturn = "";
            if (this.startDay == 9999)
                {
                    startDayReturn = "(no start)";
                }
            else
                {   
                 int startDayDigit1 = (this.startDay / 1000) % 10;
                 int startDayDigit2 = (this.startDay / 100) % 10;
                 int startDayDigit3 = (this.startDay / 10) % 10;
                 int startDayDigit4 = this.startDay % 10;

                 startDayReturn = (startDayDigit1 + startDayDigit2 + "/" + startDayDigit3 + startDayDigit4);
                }
         return startDayReturn;
      }

      public String getFormattedEndDay()
      {
         String endDayReturn = "";
         if(this.endDay == 9999)
         {
            endDayReturn = "(no end)";
         }
         else
         {
            int endDayDigit1 = (this.endDay / 1000) % 10;
            int endDayDigit2 = (this.endDay / 100) % 10;
            int endDayDigit3 = (this.endDay / 10) % 10;
            int endDayDigit4 = this.endDay % 10;

            endDayReturn = (endDayDigit1 + endDayDigit2 + "/" + endDayDigit3 + endDayDigit4);
         }
         return endDayReturn;
      }

      public String getFormattedCategory()
      {
         int cat = this.category;
         String categoryReturn = "";
         switch(cat){
            case 0:
               categoryReturn = "Tropical Storm";
               break;
            case 1:
               categoryReturn = "Hurricane Level 1";
               break;
            case 2:
               categoryReturn = "Hurricane Level 2";
               break;
            case 3:
               categoryReturn = "Hurricane Level 3";
               break;
            case 4:
               categoryReturn = "Hurricane Level 4";
               break;
            case 5:
               categoryReturn = "Hurricane Level 5";
               break;
            case 6:
               categoryReturn = "Hurricane Level 6";
               break;
            default:
               categoryReturn = "no info";
               break;
         }

         return categoryReturn; 

      }

   }
```

Sorry its alot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `"Can anyone walk me through this? Im stumped and have tried too hard thinking about this."` -- you'll be much better off asking specific questions in order to receive specific helpful answers.

Comment: I just need to know how to overall structure the code, how can two linked lists interact, etc. the detail i can code. I'm just stumped at the design phase.

Comment: I dont understand how to attach a linked list to another linked list. Thats what i need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont understand how to attach a linked list to another linked list.

You add a member of type `StormList` to class `YearNode`, along with a getter and setter method.  You could also add a convenience method `YearNode#addStorm(StormNode sn)` that would add the `StormNode` to the contained `StormList`.